# UIScrollView doesn’t seem to work in xcode 6 (iOS 8)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview, ios8

I’m trying to make a scroll view in xcode. I used the following code in xcode 5 (which worked):

view.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {

IBOutlet UIScrollView *ScrollView;
}


@end
```

view.m

```
@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [ScrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [ScrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1005)];



}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

I have seen others with this problem but none of their solutions worked for me. Note that i have size set to freedom and auto layout is turned off.

Comment: BTW, better to follow the convention to use camelCase variable names starting with a small letter, like `scrollView`.

Comment: Just a FYI - Talking about iOS 8 outside of the Official Apple forms is a breach of the NDA you signed.

Comment: What's the size of your scrollView - is it larger than your view?

Answer (score 3):

Try this - [UIScrollView with Autolayout](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oCWxHLBQ-A)

OR

try setting your content size in viewDidAppear

Comment: setting the content size in viewDidAppear did the trick for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Due to a scrollView feature in auto layout, the contentSize is being redefined. To solve this problem, you could disable auto layout or set the content size in viewDidLayoutSubviews()

```
-(void)viewWillLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    ScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,1005);
}
```

So you would want to add this code and delete the ScrollView.contentSize method in viewDidLoad.

Comment: I have the problem with AutoLayout-Size Classes, backward compatibility to iOS 7 and added your answer, but inside viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything immediately wrong with this code. I would check and makes sure that you've connected the IBOutlet properly in the Interface Builder.